# livewire wireclick component in 2 blade files laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

[Hi, how can i use my components to my other blade file with the same wire:click? I have a view components which i use in my view blade file, but i want to use it also in my index blade file with the same wire:click function.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZs8q.jpg)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8JrU.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8thM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Using nested livewire components. Inside your other blade view add your component like

```
<livewire:view></livewire:view>
```

Comment: I already tried this, but its not working :(